# Array Declaration in CFScript

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

Please consider the following documentation:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=CFScript_11.html#1161053

I'm studying the description of following code:

```
<cfscript>

    //Set the variables

    acceptedApplicants[1] = "Cora Cardozo";
    acceptedApplicants[2] = "Betty Bethone";
    acceptedApplicants[3] = "Albert Albertson";
    rejectedApplicants[1] = "Erma Erp";
    rejectedApplicants[2] = "David Dalhousie";
    rejectedApplicants[3] = "Franny Farkle";
    applicants.accepted=acceptedApplicants;
    applicants.rejected=rejectedApplicants;

    rejectCode=StructNew();
    rejectCode["David Dalhousie"] = "score";
    rejectCode["Franny Farkle"] = "too late";
```

The description says that, "Creates two one-dimensional arrays, one with the accepted applicants and another with the rejected applicants. "

I'm new to ColdFusion and I don't see any array declaration using the array keyword in the above code just like the following doc:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=arrayStruct_03.html#1121128

Please explain.

Comment: The code you've posted is not creating arrays - without first assigning an array (generally using either `ArrayNew(1)` or the shorthand of `[]`) both acceptedApplications and rejectedApplicants will be structs (same as rejectCode is) - because when you use bracket notation on a new variable (even with numeric keys), CF creates structs. Of course, some other languages refer to structs as "associative arrays" just to confuse things. (Of course, structs with numeric keys can act as arrays, so it doesn't necessarily mean the app is broken, but using real arrays is presumably more efficient.)

Comment: Of course, you should make sure there isn't an ArrayNew call higher up - above the script block. If this is in a function, there could be a `var acceptedApplicants = ArrayNew(1)` at the top of the function (earlier versions of CF required var scoping to be the first thing in a function; later versions allow it anywhere in a function).

Comment: @PeterBoughton... what you say about needing to first create the array with `arrayNew()` or `[]` is not borne out by this code: (apologies for lack of formatting: a[1]="tahi";writeDump(a);  That creates an array.  CF9.0.1... Is this a behaviour change from CF8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your `acceptedApplicants` and `rejectedApplicants` arrays

There should be

```
acceptedApplicants = [];
rejectedApplicants= [];
```

somewhere above in the code. Like Peter said, if this is in a function make sure you var those variables.